# Is there a formula to determine the domain and the range of a function composition with $n$ components? How to define domain and range here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition, elementary-functions

I was thinking about this recent question : what is the range of $f(x)= \frac {1} {\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$.

I tried to express this function as a function composition , that is,

with

- $i(x)=\frac 1x$
- $s(x)= \sqrt x$
- $m(x)= x-1$
- $q(x)= x^2$

as : $f(x)= i(s(m(q(x))))$.

- At this point I realized that it was difficult to express symbolically the domain and the range of this function composition.
- If I am correct, when the composition has only two components, one can say that :

dom $( f\circ g) = \{x| x\in$dom$(g) \land g(x)\in$dom$(f)\}$

ran$ ( f\circ g) = f[$ran$(g) \cap $dom$(f)]$.

My question is : how to express the same thing with more than 2 component functions? possibly, with $n$ components?

[image]

Comment: I think $m$ and $q$ are backwards when you composed them...

Comment: You are right! Thanks for pointing this mistake.